# Preprocessor directives indentation in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, indentation, visual-c++-2010, preprocessor-directive

I often find myself in situations where I would like to indent preprocessor directives like the rest of the code (e.g. `#if` indented like `if`). It [seems legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789073/indenting-defines), it's [common sense that it's sometimes a good thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975330/how-do-you-indent-preprocessor-statements), but Visual won't make it easy.

Is there a way to prevent the Visual C++ 2010 editor from sticking the code to the left each time I innocently press `#`? And to not break preprocessor directives indentation with auto-indent (CTRL+K, CTRL+F)? Or even better, to handle preprocessor directives like everything else?

Comment: For this reason I started using an external editor for editing heavy preprocessor code...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My approach is to keep the `#` in the first column and indent the subsequent word, as in:

```
#ifdef FIRST
#  include "first.h"
#else
#  include "second.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Except you won't be able to select multiple lines and (Shift+)Tab them.

Comment: +1 for good preprocessor style. Boost uses this style and it's much clearer which lines are preprocessor directives while maintaining branching indentation

Comment: +1 as it's indeed a good, often seen, workaround. But I still feel like proper indentation support would make me happier. So I'll wait and see if I get other answers.

Comment: Looks like that's the best solution until Microsoft decides to add the option.

Answer (score 12):

At some point visualstudio (checked in vs2015) acquired options > text editor > c/c++ > formatting > indentation > position of preprocessor directives. Choose 'leave indented'. The sample doesn't look exactly like what you want, but it works, just try it.

Comment: It looks like this setting was added in VS2015.

Comment: This is clearly what the accepted answer should now be. :)
Although it would be nice if the [Ctrl]+[K] [Ctrl]+[F] used this. :(

Answer (score 10):

In the Visual Studio 2010 options (Tools->Options)

Go to Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Tabs

Under indenting select Block instead of smart.

This will prevent the # key from forcing you to the start of the line, however if you use Ctrl+K Ctrl+F it will still apply smart formatting and remove the tabs.

Edit: This will also disable automatic indenting/unindenting in other places. Beware.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround: When you first type the `#` and Visual Studio removes your indentation, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to undo the auto formatting.