# Automatically indenting pre-processor statements

Tags: c++, indentation, code-formatting

What does everyone use to indent C++ pre-processor directives? Astyle and Gnu-Ident don't seem to be able to do this!

I think James McNellis' answer on this thread ([How do you indent preprocessor statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975330/how-do-you-indent-preprocessor-statements)) is very interesting. I've adopted this style for some time now and it would be great to be able to do this on existing code.

I just got charged with maintaining a series of classes Riddled with nested #IFDEFS/#ELSEIF/#ELSE and each of the functions are around 800 - 1000 lines (making readability and collapsing blocks very very difficult)

Answer (score 0):

1. egrep -r '^ *#' srcdir | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^\s*#\s*([^\s]+)/' | sort -u
2. based on the preprocessor keywords present in your code that above command will print implement a simple recursive indentation algo, similar to what you would use to check for symmetric brackets.

Comment: Thanks bobah! -- But that will likely not treat preprocessor directives as ordinary C++ blocks. James McNellis' suggestion and what I've seen other people do is to treat the preprocessor directive as a normal code block that gets indented with the rest of the code blocks it is currently situated in. \n I wonder if modifying astyle maybe the only solution we have! -- Theoretically it should be easy if astyle was written well enough to be able to define how #IFDEF, #ELSEIF, #ELSE and #END are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Our C and C++ prettyprinters treat well-placed conditionals as if they were part of the program structure, and indents them (and their content) accordingly. These prettyprinters include full, precise C and C++ parsers; they won't break your code when reformatting.

SO hates off-site links; check my bio.