# Initialise aggregate with include directive

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

Very quick question. I want to copy & paste textual data into the source code from the separate file using *include* directive.

Is it legal?

```
struct Record; // collection of data fields

Record rec = { #include "some_big_record.txt" };

int numbers[] = { #include "some_long_sequence_of_numbers.txt" };
```

It works on my box (GCC), but is it portable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is portable:

```
Record rec = { 
#include "some_big_record.txt" 
};
```

Comment: Good to hear that. Are white spaces allowed before **#include**?

Comment: @pic11 Add the spaces after the `#`. Like this: `#   include "data.txt"`. Edit: Just checked, actually it doesn't matter. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789073/indenting-defines.