# Can CPP preprocessing statement in Fortran be indented?

Tags: fortran, c-preprocessor, indentation, gfortran, preprocessor

I am fairly new to use Fortran preprocessing statement and have a question which is probably pretty native. Can Fortran preprocessing statement be indented? I tested using Gfortran 4.8.1 on Linux (openSUSE Leap) and it turned out I it can not be indented at all.

The following code main.f90 works with `gfortran -cpp main.f90 -o main`:

```
program main
    implicit none
#ifdef DEBUG
    print *, "I am in debug mode"
#endif 
    print *, "hello world!"
end program main
```

But the following throws an error:

```
program main
    implicit none
    #ifdef DEBUG
    print *, "I am in debug mode"
    #endif 
    print *, "hello world!"
end program main
```

The error message is `Error: Invalid character in name at (1)`. 
Does this mean that we should always write the preprocessing statement from the first beginning of the line or it is just a compiler specific rule? Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they cannot be indented because gfortran runs CPP in [traditional mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-Mode.html) which does not allow indentation. They must always start in the first column.

You could run CPP manually, but be very very careful about that.
If you use the `//` string concatenation operator somewhere the preprocessor would treat it as a comment. You must use the `-C` flag as shown by @ewcz in his/her answer which disables discarding of comments.

Some compilers supply their own FPP preprocessor which behaves differently.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Does gfortran support any other preprocessor or cpp is just the only one available?

Comment: cpp is the only one available directly through the gfortran command. But you can always run a different pre-processor manually.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the `C` preprocessor to do the processing and then compile the processed file, i.e., assuming that your program is in `main.f90`, then something like:

```
cpp -nostdinc -C -P -w main.f90 > _main.f90
gfortran -o main _main.f90
```

In this connection, this question is quite useful: [Indenting #defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789073/indenting-defines)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links is quite relevant and useful.