# Concatenate strings in a macro using gfortran

Tags: macos, macros, fortran, c-preprocessor, gfortran

The C preprocessor macro for concatenation (`##`) does not seem to work on a Mac using gfortran. Using other Fortran compilers on other systems works so I am looking for a workaround for gfortran. I have to use the `##` to create many variables so I can't do without them.

Example code:

```
#define CONCAT(x,y) x##y
program main
   integer, parameter:: CONCAT(ID,2) = 3
   print*,"Hello", ID_2
end program main
```

Compilation error with gfortran on MAC

```
gfortran m.F90 -o m
m.F90:5.23:
integer, parameter:: ID##2 = 3
                       1
Error: PARAMETER at (1) is missing an initializer
```

Comment: the usual strategy is to first pass the file to the preprocessor and then compile the preprocessed file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953392/can-cpp-preprocessing-statement-in-fortran-be-indented/38953582#38953582

Comment: gfortran is set up with tradcpp (gcc -E -traditional) to avoid the conflict between c99 // comments and Fortran concatenation. As mentioned, a typical alternative is explicit use of a different preprocessor e.g. by Makefile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`##` doesn't work in gfortran (any OS, not just Mac) because it runs CPP in the *traditional mode*.

According to [this thread the gfortran mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2016-02/msg00028.html)  the correct operator in the traditional mode is `x/**/y`, so you must distinguish between different compilers:

```
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
#define CONCAT(x,y) x/**/y
#else
#define CONCAT(x,y) x ## y
#endif
```

Others (http://c-faq.com/cpp/oldpaste.html) use this form, which behaves better when a macro passed to the CONCAT (via [Concatenating an expanded macro and a word using the Fortran preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243555/concatenating-an-expanded-macro-and-a-word-using-the-fortran-preprocessor)):

```
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
#define PASTE(a) a
#define CONCAT(a,b) PASTE(a)b
#else
#define PASTE(a) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a,b) PASTE(a,b)
#endif
```

The indirect formulation helps to expand the passed macro before the strings are concatenated (it is too late after).

Comment: Thanks for sending me here, @VladimirF. I'm looking at your second code sample, and shouldn't it be `#define PASTE(a,b) a ## b` for the non-gfortran part of the code? as in, adding `b` as an argument to the definition of `PASTE`?