# gfortran no-traditional preprocessor

Tags: fortran, gfortran, preprocessor

I want to write a module overloading a `swap` routine, which takes an array and two indices and swaps the two elements around.

This routine should work for a wide range of arrays, so I wanted to overload it:

```
module mod_swap

    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none

    interface swap
        module procedure swap_int64, swap_int32, swap_int16, &
            swap_real64, swap_real32
    end interface swap

    public :: swap
    private :: swap_int64, swap_int32, swap_int16, &
        swap_real64, swap_real32

contains

#define VAR_TYPE real
#define TYPE_KIND real64
#include  "swap.inc"
#undef TYPE_KIND

#define TYPE_KIND real32
#include  "swap.inc"
#undef TYPE_KIND
#undef VAR_TYPE

#define VAR_TYPE integer
#define TYPE_KIND int64
#include  "swap.inc"
#undef TYPE_KIND

#define TYPE_KIND int32
#include  "swap.inc"
#undef TYPE_KIND

#define TYPE_KIND int16
#include  "swap.inc"
#undef TYPE_KIND
#undef VAR_TYPE

end module mod_swap
```

with `swap.inc` being:

```
#define PASTER(x,y) x ## _ ## y
#define EVALUATOR(x,y) PASTER(x,y)
#define SWAP EVALUATOR(swap, TYPE_KIND)

    subroutine SWAP(a, i, j)
        implicit none
        VAR_TYPE(kind=TYPE_KIND), intent(inout) :: a(:)
        integer, intent(in) :: i, j
        VAR_TYPE(kind=TYPE_KIND) t
        t = a(i)
        a(i) = a(j)
        a(j) = t
    end subroutine SWAP
```

When I run `gfortran -o test.o -c -cpp test.F90` it fails, and when I run `gfortran -E -cpp test.F90` I find out why: the `SWAP` macro has been expanded to `swap ## _ ##  int16`, not `swap_int16` as expected.

However, `cpp` directly works:

```
$ cpp test.F90 > test.f90
$ gfortran -c -o test.o test.f90
```

After browsing this forum and Google in general, I have deduced that the issue is this:

> The preprocessor is run in traditional mode.

And indeed, `cpp --traditional` exhibits the same behaviour as `gfortran -E -cpp`

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a better way to implement this routine so that I don't have to repeat the same instructions just because the array type has changed. (Note that the variable `t` needs to have the same type as `a`).
2. Is there a way to make `gfortran` use the non-traditional preprocessor?
3. If not, how would I do what I want to do with the traditional preprocessor?

Comment: Answer to (2) is 'no'.  Answer to (3) is to directly use cpp as you have demonstrated.  With (3) be prepare for possible odd results as modern C preprocessor syntax and Fortran syntax have conflicts.  Answer to (1) probably lies in Fortran's submodule feature.

Comment: cpp in non-traditional mode will treat `//` as comment delimiters. The traditional mode is used by gfortran because it is necessary to not break the Fortran code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can implement what you are looking for by using compiler-dependent preprocessor macros.  Note that a similar case was already discussed and answered in [Concatenating an expanded macro and a word using the Fortran preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243555/concatenating-an-expanded-macro-and-a-word-using-the-fortran-preprocessor).  I believe it could be adapted to your case as follows:

   ```
   #if defined(__GFORTRAN__) || defined(NAGFOR)
   #define PASTE(a) a
   #define ADD_TRAIL_USCORE(a) PASTE(a)_
   #define CAT(a,b) ADD_TRAIL_USCORE(a)b
   #else
   #define PASTE(a,b) a ## _ ## b
   #define CAT(a,b) PASTE(a,b)
   #endif

   #define SWAP CAT(swap,TYPE_KIND)
   ```

   Note that

   - [The above-mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243555/concatenating-an-expanded-macro-and-a-word-using-the-fortran-preprocessor) states that *"basically most Fortran compilers (i.e. Intel and PGI) use a relatively normal C-preprocessor with a token pasting operator"*.  My understanding is that the NAG compiler also can't deal with `##`, and hence needs to be added to the exception.
   - In the last `#define` above, there is no space between `swap,` and `TYPE_KIND`.
2. Not that I know of.
3. As @Vladimir pointed out in the comments, you probably don't want to do that, since it would break the Fortran concatenation operator `//`.

Comment: Other compilers use often `fpp`, a separate pre-processor derived from the C preprocessor (likely not the GNU one) and adapted slightly for Fortran.

Comment: `#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
#define CONCAT(x,y) x/**/y` may also work in simpler cases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679689/concatenate-strings-in-a-macro-using-gfortran?noredirect=1&lq=1