# Is there any difference between #define and # define?

Tags: format, c-preprocessor, indentation, c99

I'm studying C and, according to the style guide everyone in my school must abide, I should put a space between `#` and `define`, but never in `#ifndef` or `#endif`, for instance. If I do either, it says I have "bad preprocessor indentation". I was searching for the reason and couldn't find it, not even in the C99 ISO. In the ISO, by the way, there are 110 instances of `#define` and only 12 of `# define`, which makes me want to stick to the version with no spaces. But why would it be a bad style choice? If it's for indentation, why only a single space and not a tab or multiple spaces? Sorry if it's a dumb question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Namely, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170900/11683